# Remove grouping from numpunct of std::locale

Tags: c++, locale, customization

I'm unsuccessfully trying to strip grouping (thousands separator) from std::locale.

I need to strip it from locale set in OS (for example sk_SK locale) but retain all others locale dependent formatting characteristics (decimal separator, etc).

Some of my attempts are in the code bellow. Looks like combining locale with *no_separator* strip all numpunct characteristics and reset them all back to "C" locale, instead of modifying just do_grouping characteristic.

(Windows10, VS, SDK 10.0, MSVC v142)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <sstream>

struct no_separator : std::numpunct<char>
{
    protected:
    virtual string_type do_grouping() const
    {
        return "\0";
    } // groups of 0 (disable)
};

int main()
{
    std::cout.precision(8);
    std::cout.width(12);

    std::cout << "Test \"C\": " << 1234.5678 << std::endl;      // OK - 1234.5678

    std::locale skSKLocale("sk_SK");

    std::cout.imbue(skSKLocale);
    std::cout << "Test skSK: " << 1234.5678 << std::endl;       // OK - 1 234,5678

    //std::locale::global(skSKLocale);
    std::locale localeNoThousandsSeparator = std::locale(skSKLocale, new no_separator());
    std::locale finishedLoc = skSKLocale.combine<std::numpunct<char>>(localeNoThousandsSeparator);

    std::cout.imbue(localeNoThousandsSeparator);
    std::cout << "Test localeNoThousandsSeparator: " << 1234.5678 << std::endl;     // BAD - expected 1234,5678, got 1234.5678
    std::cout.imbue(finishedLoc);
    std::cout << "Test finishedLoc: " << 1234.5678 << std::endl;    // BAD - expected 1234,5678, got 1234.5678
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: So you expect that do_grouping of no_seperator will get somehow used by the locale skSKLocale after combine, right? I tried to get the output for sk_SK locale in clang since it was not available there. Managed to do this: https://godbolt.org/z/he39P3Eo4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your facet has no idea about the sk locale. It just uses the default implementation. You may want to forward all other methods of your custom `numpunct` to the relevant facet of whatever locale you are modifying, something like:

```
struct no_separator : std::numpunct<char>
{ 
    no_separator(std::locale& base_locale) : 
      np(std::use_facet< std::numpunct<char> >(base_locale)) {
    }

  protected:
    string_type do_grouping() const override { return ""; }
    char_type do_decimal_point() const override { return np.decimal_point(); }
    char_type do_thousands_sep() const override { return np.thousands_sep(); }
    string_type do_truename() const override { return np.truename(); }
    string_type do_falsename() const override { return np.truename(); }

    const std::numpunct<char> & np;
};
```

Comment: The type is already inheriting from `std::numpunct<char>`. Does it need another (reference to) `std::numpunct<char>`? Maybe it could use `numpunct_byname`?

Comment: @cpplearner The reference refers not to a `std::numpunct<char>` object, but to something derived from it and tailored for a specific locale. `numpunct_byname` would do exactly the same thing.

Comment: Many thanks to both @n. m. could be an AI and kiner_shah for your answers and code! So whole std::numpunct must be defined, otherwise non defined functions will fallback to classic "C" locale (because instance itself is based on "classic" locale).